# conditional probability more than one given at least one

Tags: conditional-probability

I'm working on a binomial conditional probability question for a practice exam. The question is as follows: You have a box of n=40 bolts. The probability of a bolt being faulty is p=0.005. You are told that at least one of the bolts is faulty, and asked: What is the probability of more than one bolt being faulty given that at least one is faulty?

With n=40, p=0.005 and X=faulty bolts, I see this as: `P(X=>2 | X=>1)`.

I believe the solution is:

```
P(X≥2 | X≥1) = P(X≥2 ∩ X≥1)/P(X≥1)
```

Is this correct? And if so, how do I calculate the numerator?
So far I have:

P(X≥1):

```
P(X=>1)= 1 - (1-p)^n = 1 - 0.8183 = 0.1817
```

P(X≥2):

```
P(X≥2)=1-(P(X=1)+P(X=0))= 0.0172
```

And then I am extremely unsure about how to proceed. I have spent hours reading and searching online and I haven't been able to find the answer. I would really appreciate some help.

Comment: The important thing is that $P(X \geq 2 \cap X \geq 1)$ = $P(X \geq 2)$, since if $X$ is greater than or equal to 2, it is also greater than or equal to 1.

Comment: Thank you. Does that mean that `P(X≥2 | X≥1) = P(X≥2)/P(X≥1)` ? Is it really that simple?

Comment: Yes, that's correct :)

Comment: Thank you so much. Thinking about it without the formula, I see that that makes sense. One last question to make sure I understand it correctly (sorry): If I wanted to find `P(X≥3 | X≥1)` I would similarly put do `P(X≥3 | X≥1) = P(X≥3)/P(X≥1)` because P(X≥1) is contained within the P(X≥3)?

Comment: Yep, you've got it.